# How to Merge two columns into one in R

Tags: r, dataframe, merge

I have the two columns and I am trying to merge the two columns into one.

```
library(tibble)
a <- tribble(
    ~Life_Expectancy_At_Birth_1960, ~Life_Expectancy_At_Birth_2013,
    65.5693658536586,                75.3286585365854,
    32.328512195122,                 60.0282682926829,
    32.9848292682927,                51.8661707317073,
    62.2543658536585,                77.537243902439,
    52.2432195121951,                77.1956341463415,
)
```

The result I want is:

```
    Life_Expectancy
    65.5693658536586 
    75.3286585365854   
    32.328512195122  
    60.0282682926829  
    32.9848292682927    
    51.8661707317073 
    62.2543658536585  
    77.537243902439  
    52.2432195121951  
    77.1956341463415
```

and so on

Any help would be great. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's one way with re-shaping via `pivot_longer()`:

```
dat <- tibble::tribble(
    ~Life_Expectancy_At_Birth_1960,                   ~Life_Expectancy_At_Birth_2013,
65.5693658536586, 75.3286585365854, 
32.328512195122,  60.0282682926829, 
32.9848292682927, 51.8661707317073, 
62.2543658536585, 77.537243902439, 
52.2432195121951, 77.1956341463415)
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)

dat %>% mutate(obs= 1:n()) %>% 
    pivot_longer(-obs, names_to="variable", values_to="var") %>% 
    arrange(obs, variable) %>% 
    select(-c(obs, variable))

# # A tibble: 10 x 1
#    var
#    <dbl>
# 1  65.6
# 2  75.3
# 3  32.3
# 4  60.0
# 5  33.0
# 6  51.9
# 7  62.3
# 8  77.5
# 9  52.2
# 10  77.2
```

Answer (score 0):

You probably want `melt` from the `data.table` package. Without seeing more details of what your whole data looks like it's difficult to be more specific than that.